# Javascript Array перебрать массив

Tags: javascript

У меня динамически можно создавать группы, у каждой группы своя цена.

На сайте есть форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно для группы один в диапазоне от 1-10 одну цену от 10-20 другая итд.. И последняя группа выводить текст цена по запросу любой текст который введен в поле последней группы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
group_count =1     
diapazon_ot[group_count] =  1;
diapazon_do[group_count] =  10;
czena_na_cheloveka[group_count] =  5;

group_count =2      
diapazon_ot[group_count] =  10;
diapazon_do[group_count] =  20;
czena_na_cheloveka[group_count] =  10;

group_count =3      
diapazon_ot[group_count] =  20;
diapazon_do[group_count] =  30;
czena_na_cheloveka[group_count] =  15;

group_count =4     
diapazon_ot[group_count] =  30;
diapazon_do[group_count] =  40;
czena_na_cheloveka[group_count] =  "Цена индивидуальна ";
```

С последней группой проблем нет что вроде этого можно adults это из формы католичество человек

```
//выше этого индивидуально
if (adults > diapazon_do.length) {
    alert( 'Максимум' );                                          
    var  person_max = czena_na_cheloveka[diapazon_do.length];
}
```

Тут я так понимаю нужно в цикле перебирать , вот только не пойму как.

Comment: *от 1-10 одну цену от 10-20 другая итд..* Рискуешь по два раза выводить одно и то же (например, при значении 10) - или на одной из границ нужно использовать строгое неравенство, а на другой строгое. Ну и начинать лучше таки с нуля, а не с единицы.

Comment: да была такая проблема , при другом подходе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < diapazon_do.length - 1; i++) {
  if (adults > diapazon_do[i] && adults <= diapazon_do[i]) {
    sum = czena_na_cheloveka[i];
    break;
  }
}
if (adults > diapazon_ot[diapazon_do.length - 1 && 
    adults <= diapazon_do[diapazon_do.length - 1]) {
  sum = czena_na_cheloveka[diapazon_do.length - 1];
} else if (adults > diapazon_do[diapazon_do.length - 1]) {
  sum = "Too many people, result - unknown.";
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Цикл конечно сильный , я такой точно не осилил бы )) но немного не то

Comment: 1 группа  от 1-  до 10 цена за все группу 5 руб  , пока на форме я ввожу от одного до 5 , то цена так и остается 5 за все группу. Когда перехожу к 11 то это уже диапазон из 2 группы и цена 10 так и остается пока не превышу следующий диапазон.

Comment: Количество групп в массиве известно , также известен диапазон у каждой группы от и до как оформить этот переход с увеличение цены от одной группы к другой не пойму.

Answer (score -1):

```
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 1; i < diapazon_do.length - 1; i++) {
if (adults > diapazon_ot[i] && adults <= diapazon_do[i]) {
    sum = czena_na_group[i];
price_per_person = Number(sum);
console.log(sum,'1');
break;
   } 
 }

if (adults > diapazon_ot[diapazon_do.length - 1] && adults <= diapazon_do[diapazon_ot.length - 1]) {
sum = czena_na_group[diapazon_do.length - 1];
console.log(sum,'2');
} else if (adults > diapazon_do[diapazon_do.length - 1]) {
sum = "Too many people, result - unknown.";
console.log(sum,'3');
}
```

Comment: Вместо того чтобы писать еще один ответ с куском моего кода, Вы могли просто принять мой ответ, щелкнув по знаку "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: В поле цена , цена на группу  и она не должна меняться , пока количество человек не превысит диапазон первой группы

Comment: Рекомендация: не называйте переменную с ценой на группу `czena_na_cheloveka`.

Comment: я понял просто сам сначала тоже не понимал что нужно назвал так переменные , уже три раза переделывал , человек так объясняет , просто не поменял